# Sluggish UI/video performance on NVIDIA GeForce 8600 GS and very high CPU usage

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

I am a newbie in Linux and installed Ubuntu in my really old laptop **Dell Vostro 1500**. Everything seems to be working fine except the graphics driver. Initially, I didn't understand that Linux is using the default driver as all colours were looking good however the UI looks very slow and sluggish. Moving window or any new popup comes up so late.

System configuration:

- Intel Centrino 1.7GHz dual-core
- 3 GB RAM
- 320 GB HDD
- NVIDIA GeForce 8600 GS
- Ubuntu 13.10

Firstly I tried to install with the latest **Ubuntu** provided NVIDIA driver, but it didn't work and caused `x-server` to crash. I used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-latest`. Also tried installing the recommended driver from **Device Manager**, that didn't work either. I ended up with `640x480` resolution.

After lots of Googling, I came up with unofficial NVIDIA drivers from `x-swat` which seems to fix my resolution and a loaded NVIDIA driver. I used the command below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

I have also checked if NVIDIA is loaded using

```
lsmod | egrep "nvidia"
```

which resulted

```
nvidia              10304704  44
```

I have also checked the driver version from **NVIDIA X Server Settings** from start menu which resulted `304.117`

I have also black-listed the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist intel_agp
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
```

I have also tried to tweak NVIDIA settings with these following commands:

```
nvidia-settings -a InitialPixmapPlacement=2 -a GlyphCache=1
```

and also added:

```
Option "PixmapCacheSize" "300000"
Option "OnDemandVBlankInterrupts" "True"
```

to my `xorg.conf` `Device` section.

Still, everything is slow, resizing/moving windows, scrolling, **and also deserves mentioning video playback is extremely choppy.**

It would be lovely to have a response from Linux gurus :)